# Append csv by row from two lists in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have two lists in Python: 'away' and 'home'.  I want to append them to an already existing csv file such that I write a row solely of 1st element of away, then 1st element of home, then the 2nd element of away, then the 2nd element of home,...etc with empty spaces in between them, so it will be like this:

```
away1
home1

away2
home2

away3
home3
```

and so on and so on.  The size of the away and home lists is the same, but might change day to day.  How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a row or column? And what have you tried so far - can you show us some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want the useful and flexible `zip` built-in.

```
>>> away = ["away1", "away2", "away3"]
>>> home = ["home1", "home2", "home3"]
>>> list(zip(away, home))
[('away1', 'home1'), ('away2', 'home2'), ('away3', 'home3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

away = ["away1", "away2", "away3"]
home = ["home1", "home2", "home3"]
record_list = [ list(item) for item in list(zip(away, home)) ]
print record_list
with open("sample.csv", "a") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerows(record_list)

# record_list =  [['away1', 'home1'], ['away2', 'home2'], ['away3', 'home3']]
```

You should use **writerows** method to write multiple list at a time to each row.

[image]